# how to write a macro on multiplication table?

Tags: macros, packages, pstricks

There is an example on macro of MultTable in the manual of Pstricks. I just copied the codes and pasted into the tex file, but it doesn't work. who can help me modify it?

```
\documentclass[pstricks,margin=1mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{pstricks,pst-poly,pst-text,pst-key}

\begin{document}


\begin{pspicture*}(12,3)

% “Start”, “End” and “Value” parameters
\define@key{psset}{Start}{\pst@getint{#1}{\MultTable@Start}}
\define@key{psset}{End}{\pst@getint{#1}{\MultTable@End}}
\define@key{psset}{Value}{\pst@getint{#1}{\MultTable@Value}}
\setkeys{psset}{Start=1,End=5,Value=2}% Default values

% Main macro for “multiplication table” object
\def\MultTable{\def\pst@par{}\pst@object{MultTable}}

 \def\MultTable@i{{%
 \use@par% Assignment of local parameters
 \pst@cnth=\MultTable@End
 \advance\pst@cnth-\MultTable@Start
 \advance\pst@cnth\@ne
 \multido{\iValue=\MultTable@Start+\@ne}{\pst@cnth}{%
 \pst@cntg=\iValue
 \multiply\pst@cntg\MultTable@Value
 \iValue$\times$\MultTable@Value = \the\pst@cntg
 \ifnum\multidocount=\pst@cnth\else; \fi}}}

 \MultTable


\MultTable[Value=9]

\setkeys{psset}{Value=6}

\MultTable[Start=6,End=11]

\MultTable[Start=19742,End=19742]
\end{pspicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: you need `@` to be a letter so place those commands in a local .sty file or surround with `\makeatletter`  ...  `\makeatother`

Comment: Do you mean: I can just put those commands into the environment \makeatletter ... \makeatother, but it doesn't work.

Comment: \makeatletter
% “Start”, “End” and “Value” parameters
\define@key{psset}{Start}{\pst@getint{#1}{\MultTable@Start}}
...
 \ifnum\multidocount=\pst@cnth\else; \fi}}}
\makeatother

Comment: these are the all commands I can find in the manual of pstricks.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/51761/discussion-between-david-carlisle-and-dozer).

Comment: `\setkeys{psset}{Value=6}` can be written as `\psset{Value=6}` if you use `\define@key[psset]{}{Value}{\pst@getint{#1}\MultTable@Value}`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The documentation is a bit scanty about the code; the preliminary definitions should go between `\makeatletter` and `\makeatother`, preferably before `\begin{document}`. In this case there's no need to use a `pspicture`, because you aren't really drawing.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pstricks,pst-poly,pst-text,pst-key}

\makeatletter
% “Start”, “End” and “Value” parameters
\define@key{psset}{Start}{\pst@getint{#1}{\MultTable@Start}}
\define@key{psset}{End}{\pst@getint{#1}{\MultTable@End}}
\define@key{psset}{Value}{\pst@getint{#1}{\MultTable@Value}}
\setkeys{psset}{Start=1,End=5,Value=2}% Default values

% Main macro for “multiplication table” object
\def\MultTable{\def\pst@par{}\pst@object{MultTable}}

 \def\MultTable@i{{%
 \use@par% Assignment of local parameters
 \pst@cnth=\MultTable@End
 \advance\pst@cnth-\MultTable@Start
 \advance\pst@cnth\@ne
 \multido{\iValue=\MultTable@Start+\@ne}{\pst@cnth}{%
 \pst@cntg=\iValue
 \multiply\pst@cntg\MultTable@Value
 \iValue$\times$\MultTable@Value = \the\pst@cntg
 \ifnum\multidocount=\pst@cnth\else; \fi}}}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\MultTable

\MultTable[Value=9]

\setkeys{psset}{Value=6}

\MultTable[Start=6,End=11]

\MultTable[Start=19742,End=19742]

\end{document}
```

[image]

How a `multtable.sty` package should be written? Here it is

```
\ProvidesPackage{multtab}[2017/01/14 v. 0]
\RequirePackage{pstricks,pst-poly,pst-text,pst-key}
% “Start”, “End” and “Value” parameters
\define@key{psset}{Start}{\pst@getint{#1}{\MultTable@Start}}
\define@key{psset}{End}{\pst@getint{#1}{\MultTable@End}}
\define@key{psset}{Value}{\pst@getint{#1}{\MultTable@Value}}
\setkeys{psset}{Start=1,End=5,Value=2}% Default values

% Main macro for “multiplication table” object
\def\MultTable{\def\pst@par{}\pst@object{MultTable}}

 \def\MultTable@i{{%
 \use@par% Assignment of local parameters
 \pst@cnth=\MultTable@End
 \advance\pst@cnth-\MultTable@Start
 \advance\pst@cnth\@ne
 \multido{\iValue=\MultTable@Start+\@ne}{\pst@cnth}{%
 \pst@cntg=\iValue
 \multiply\pst@cntg\MultTable@Value
 \iValue$\times$\MultTable@Value = \the\pst@cntg
 \ifnum\multidocount=\pst@cnth\else; \fi}}}

\endinput
```

Save this as `multtable.sty` and then after `\usepackage{multtable}` the command `\MultTable` will do its job:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{multtable}

\begin{document}

\MultTable

\MultTable[Value=9]

\setkeys{psset}{Value=6}

\MultTable[Start=6,End=11]

\MultTable[Start=19742,End=19742]

\end{document}
```

Comment: thank you very much, the result is the same as the manual.

Comment: Can I change the commands into a package. What should I do?

Comment: I have done according to your instruction. but it showed the error message: Document Class: article 2014/09/29 v1.4h Standard LaTeX document class
(d:/texlive/2016/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/size10.clo)) (./multtable.sty
! Undefined control sequence.
l.2 \define@key
               {psset}{Start}{\pst@getint{#1}{\MultTable@Start}}
? x
No pages of output.
Transcript written on MultTable.log.

Comment: @dozer I added an example of usage.

Comment: I used a same tex file, but returned the above error message.